# Google Maps, Ellipse inside rectangle bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the great [Google Maps Shapes library](https://github.com/monkeyherder/v3-eshapes/blob/master/eshapes.js) to draw ellipses on my map with four given points, trouble is the ellipse is breaking the boundaries of the "rectangle/square" I envisaged.

[edit- updated image]

**See this graphic for an example of how it's breaking the boundaries:**

[image]

The pink points are the bounding rectangle I want (ignore the green ones)

How do I keep this ellipse inside those bounds (the goal here being it matches the outer reaches of the blue/gree and orange line originating from the centre.)

[edit]

**The placement of *some* markers but these will change depending on user input**

```
_s.OVAL_MARKERS = [
    // Top
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.583487043925224, -0.16044229844476376),
    // Right
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.58339184515312, -0.16013348842307096),
    // Bottom
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.58317916077958, -0.16026707625337622),
    // Left
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.583331361647325, -0.16064041535150864)
];
```

**The code I'm using to create the oval (modified for this posting for clarity of variables)**

```
var b = new _g.LatLngBounds();

_s.OVAL_MARKERS.forEach(function (m) {
    b.extend(m);
});

var major_axis = _gs.computeDistanceBetween(
    b.getNorthEast(),
    new _g.LatLng(
        b.getSouthWest().lat(),
        b.getNorthEast().lng()
    )
) / 2;
var minor_axis = _gs.computeDistanceBetween(
    new _g.LatLng(b.getCenter().lat(), b.getSouthWest().lng()),
    new _g.LatLng(b.getCenter().lat(), b.getNorthEast().lng())
) / 2;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps - draw ellipse based off 4 coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157880/google-maps-draw-ellipse-based-off-4-coordinates)

Comment: it is not a duplicate, he is asking "how to make the ellipse" I'm asking how to make the ellipse only as large as a bounding rectangle.

Comment: But the solution is the same.

Comment: No. It isn't. The solution for that chaps question is using the library I mention at first in my post. My question is not about **adding** the ellipse but rather **modifying** the ellipse to be bound to my rectangle.

Comment: Provide your four points. And the code you are using to create the ellipse.

Comment: Added the code, are you able to remove the duplicate flag from the post since it isn't a duplicate.

Comment: Thought you wanted [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_eshapes_ellipse_fromPoints.html).

Comment: Your solution was close but now it seems a bit too small? Is there any way I can sort that out? I've updated my code above and the screenshot.

Comment: It wasn't a solution.  As you pointed out, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: It worked though :P it's okay for now. If you post the code as an answer I will mark it as correct once I get confirmation from the client!

Comment: Then it was a duplicate of the other post.

Answer (score 1):

Your minor axis calculation is completely wrong. Right now, you're making an ellipse that will pass through all four points. Instead of doing this, what you will need to do is to compute the distance between the edges. In other words:

```
var minorAxis = _gs.computeDistanceBetween(_m[1], _m[3]);
var majorAxis = _gs.computeDistanceBetween(_m[1], _m[2]);
```

(Assuming that 1 is a vertex connected to 2 and 3)

This will give you smaller axis lengths, which is what you are looking for. The next step is to define the orientation of it. I have never drawn an ellipse in Google Maps, so I won't be able to help you on that one.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html for some useful ellipse info, by the way, including a list of formulas to bound eclipses to various shapes.