# How to draw an oval shape on Google Maps V3?

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I am trying to 'draw' an oval shape on Google Maps V3. I can't really seem to find an easy way to do this.

At the moment I am doing this using a series of polygons but as you can see from my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/zsmzfh66/), doing it this way makes it a difficult task in making a 'smooth' oval shape.

Is there a better way to do this?

This is what I have at the moment:-

```
/* Google Map - Areas we cover */

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2576646,-0.3258271);

function initialize() {
    var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

    var isDraggable = w > 480 ? true : false;
    var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: center,
    scrollwheel:  false,
    draggable: isDraggable,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('areas'),
    mapOptions);
    var styles = [
        {"featureType":"landscape.man_made","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-63"},{"lightness":"23"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-100"},{"lightness":"25"}]},{"featureType":"landscape.natural.terrain","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"0"},{"color":"#95bf97"},{"lightness":"59"}]},{"featureType":"poi.school","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"5"},{"hue":"#ff0000"},{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"poi.sports_complex","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"lightness":"5"},{"saturation":"-100"}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":"-85"},{"lightness":"12"}]}    
    ];

    // Areas Circle Polygon

    var myCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416,-0.142822),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.426614,-0.845947),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.303145,-1.109619),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.110420,-1.252441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.958427,-1.065674),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.833698,-0.681152),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.785102,-0.043945),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.840636,0.362549),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.965346,0.845947),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.110420,0.966797),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.296276,0.966797),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.412912,0.747070),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416,0.010986),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416,-0.109863)
    ];
    var polyOptions = {
    path: myCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#21509b",
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#21509b",
    fillOpacity: 0.3
    }
    var it = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
    it.setMap(map);


map.setOptions({styles: styles});

}

initialize();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps - draw ellipse based off 4 coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157880/google-maps-draw-ellipse-based-off-4-coordinates)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option (which is really what you are doing, but with higher resolution) would be to use a version of [Mike Williams' eshapes library](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/eshapes.htm) ported to v3.

- related question: [Google maps - draw ellipse based off 4 coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157880/google-maps-draw-ellipse-based-off-4-coordinates)

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/x99jLf33/1/)

**code snippet:**

```js
/* Google Map - Areas we cover */

var center = new google.maps.LatLng(51.2576646, -0.3258271);

function initialize() {
  var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);

  var isDraggable = w > 480 ? true : false;
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 7,
    center: center,
    scrollwheel: false,
    draggable: isDraggable,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    zoomControl: true
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('areas'),
    mapOptions);
  var styles = [{
    "featureType": "landscape.man_made",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": "-63"
    }, {
      "lightness": "23"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": "-100"
    }, {
      "lightness": "25"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "landscape.natural.terrain",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": "0"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.park",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": "0"
    }, {
      "color": "#95bf97"
    }, {
      "lightness": "59"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.school",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "lightness": "5"
    }, {
      "hue": "#ff0000"
    }, {
      "saturation": "-100"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "poi.sports_complex",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "lightness": "5"
    }, {
      "saturation": "-100"
    }]
  }, {
    "featureType": "road.local",
    "elementType": "geometry.fill",
    "stylers": [{
      "saturation": "-85"
    }, {
      "lightness": "12"
    }]
  }];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  // Areas Circle Polygon

  var myCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416, -0.142822),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.426614, -0.845947),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.303145, -1.109619),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.110420, -1.252441),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.958427, -1.065674),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.833698, -0.681152),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.785102, -0.043945),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.840636, 0.362549),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.965346, 0.845947),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.110420, 0.966797),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.296276, 0.966797),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.412912, 0.747070),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416, 0.010986),
    new google.maps.LatLng(51.522416, -0.109863)
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < myCoordinates.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(myCoordinates[i]);
  }
  var major_axis = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(bounds.getNorthEast(), new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getSouthWest().lat(), bounds.getNorthEast().lng())) / 2;
  var minor_axis = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
    new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getCenter().lat(), bounds.getSouthWest().lng()),
    new google.maps.LatLng(bounds.getCenter().lat(), bounds.getNorthEast().lng())) / 2;

  // === Ellipse ===
  var point = bounds.getCenter(); // new google.maps.LatLng(43,-78);
  var ellipse = google.maps.Polygon.Ellipse(point, major_axis, minor_axis, 0, "#000000", 2, 1, "#ffff00", 0.5);
  ellipse.setMap(map);
  var polyOptions = {
    path: myCoordinates,
    strokeColor: "#21509b",
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: "#21509b",
    fillOpacity: 0.2
  }
  var it = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
  it.setMap(map);
  map.setOptions({
    styles: styles
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);


// This Javascript is based on code provided by the
// Community Church Javascript Team
// http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
// http://econym.org.uk/gmap/

// EShapes.js
//
// Based on an idea, and some lines of code, by "thetoy" 
//
//   This Javascript is provided by Mike Williams
//   Community Church Javascript Team
//   http://www.bisphamchurch.org.uk/   
//   http://econym.org.uk/gmap/
//
//   This work is licenced under a Creative Commons Licence
//   http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.0/uk/
//
// Version 0.0 04/Apr/2008 Not quite finished yet
// Version 1.0 10/Apr/2008 Initial release
// Version 3.0 12/Oct/2011 Ported to v3 by Lawrence Ross
google.maps.Polygon.Ellipse = function(point, r1, r2, rotation, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts) {
  rotation = rotation || 0;
  return google.maps.Polygon.Shape(point, r1, r2, r1, r2, rotation, 100, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts)
}

google.maps.Polygon.Shape = function(point, r1, r2, r3, r4, rotation, vertexCount, strokeColour, strokeWeight, Strokepacity, fillColour, fillOpacity, opts, tilt) {
  var rot = -rotation * Math.PI / 180;
  var points = [];
  var latConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + 0.1, point.lng())) * 10;
  var lngConv = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat(), point.lng() + 0.1)) * 10;
  var step = (360 / vertexCount) || 10;

  var flop = -1;
  if (tilt) {
    var I1 = 180 / vertexCount;
  } else {
    var I1 = 0;
  }
  for (var i = I1; i <= 360.001 + I1; i += step) {
    var r1a = flop ? r1 : r3;
    var r2a = flop ? r2 : r4;
    flop = -1 - flop;
    var y = r1a * Math.cos(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var x = r2a * Math.sin(i * Math.PI / 180);
    var lng = (x * Math.cos(rot) - y * Math.sin(rot)) / lngConv;
    var lat = (y * Math.cos(rot) + x * Math.sin(rot)) / latConv;

    points.push(new google.maps.LatLng(point.lat() + lat, point.lng() + lng));
  }
  return (new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: points,
    strokeColor: strokeColour,
    strokeWeight: strokeWeight,
    strokeOpacity: Strokepacity,
    fillColor: fillColour,
    fillOpacity: fillOpacity
  }))
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#areas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="areas"></div>
```